# \newcommand with \raisebox in section title

Tags: macros, sectioning, errors

I have defined the following command to typeset 'C++':

```
\newcommand{\Cpp}{C\raisebox{-.23ex}{\texttt{++}}}
```

Using the command in a paragraph works as expected.
However, I can't use it in a section title.
I seems like it has something to do with `\raisebox`.

Here an mwe:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\Cpp}{C\raisebox{-.23ex}{\texttt{++}}}

\begin{document}    
\section{\Cpp} % doesn't work! because of \raisebox ?
\Cpp-Compiler
\end{document}
```

How can I redefine the `\Cpp` command to work in a section title?

Comment: `\section{\protect\Cpp}` should work.

Comment: In my point of view the should be some spacing after `++` -- It does not look nice in conjunction with `-Compiler` (See the output below) -- I used it unchanged from the OP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such highly fragile content should either be preceded with `\protect` or (if expansion is not an issue) use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Alternatively, use `\robustify` from `etoolbox`, `\NewDocumentCommand` (or `\DeclareDocumentCommand`) from `xparse` or a `expl3` approach with `\cs_new_protected_nopar`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for robustify
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Cpp}{C\raisebox{-.23ex}{\texttt{++}}}
\newcommand{\OtherCpp}{C\raisebox{-.23ex}{\texttt{++}}}
\newcommand{\YetAnotherCpp}{C\raisebox{-.23ex}{\texttt{++}}}
\newrobustcmd{\EvenYetAnotherCpp}{C\raisebox{-.23ex}{\texttt{++}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\EvenMoreAnotherCpp}{}{C\raisebox{-.23ex}{\texttt{++}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \CppWithExpl {
  C\raisebox{-.23ex}{\texttt{++}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\robustify{\YetAnotherCpp}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents
\section{\Cpp}
\section{\protect\OtherCpp\ with \texttt{\textbackslash protect}} 
\section{\YetAnotherCpp\ with \texttt{\textbackslash robustify}} 
\section{\EvenYetAnotherCpp\ with \texttt{\textbackslash newrobustcmd}} 
\section{\EvenMoreAnotherCpp\ with \texttt{\textbackslash NewDocumentCommand}} 
\section{\CppWithExpl\ with \texttt{\textbackslash cs\_new\_protected\_nopar}}
\Cpp-Compiler 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very robust `;^)`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I should add some `\cs_new:Nn` versions as well ;-)

Comment: Since you seem to be collecting methods, you should mention `\protected\def` which is what it all boils down to :)

Comment: @Manuel: That's too basic :-P